# Java JComboBox cannot add or remove item

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Recently, am facing a issue where i neither can add items into the JCombobox nor remove items from the JComboBox. If i test the same code in Eclipse Marse IDE it works but in netbeans its not working. Can I know the reason for this to happen.

This is the code which giving me problem:

```
public javax.swing.JComboBox<File> getJcmbSelectFile() {
    return jcmbSelectFile;
}

jcmbSelectFile.removeAllItems();
```

The error its showing is undefined symbol jcmbSelectFile. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Symbol undefined is symbol undefined. Are you absolutely positive that you have it defined? Can you create MCVE ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) with the code you work on in netbeans?

Comment: yes i am positive because the same code in eclipse its working

Comment: i have even already imported the jcombobox

Comment: why you don't use event listener in your JComboBox ?!

Comment: use item listeners to get selected item in your comboBox and do whatever you want! check this for example http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/GetselectedItemfromJComboBox.htm